# Geometry Nodes: Instance on curve pointing at the next instance (3.5.1)

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

I'm trying to make some tank tracks that follow a curve without deforming the links.

What I've come up with is instancing one of the track links on a square face that is arrayed and following the curve. (I'm not using geometry nodes for this because none of the tutorials that I have found for instancing on faces aligned with the normal currently work on 3.5.1. I'd be glad to know how to do that as well but I can leave that for a different question)

[image]

This works for the most part but the curve modifier slightly deforms some of the faces of the array when the curve does a sharp turn. There's also the issue that the instances are not real and I have to manually realize them before exporting them since the 'realize instances' node doesn't work with them for some reason.

I was wondering if there's a way to use Geometry Nodes to instance the track links directly on the curve and have their rotation pointing to the next point in the curve (Respecting the tilt of the curve as well). There are several tutorials on how to align instances to the tangent of the curve but I have not found any that talk about how to do this. I'm not knowledgeable about geometry nodes but I think it should be possible to get the coordinates of the next instance and use that to align them?

If it is possible, would it also be possible to rotate each instance 90º compared to the previous one so that it can be used to make chains as well?